# Custom post template doen't have any

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to create a custom post page. I have created a gallery-post.php page inside my theme file and put the following code in it:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Gallery Post
 * Template Post Type: post
 */
?>
```

As soon as I saved the file the option "Gallery Post" appeared on "Post Attributes" section of "Add Post" page. Now when I assign that template to my page I expect the post to appear empty since as you see there is nothing on the page and it is only that 6 lines but the page appears as if the template page doesn't have any effect here.

Actually at first I had some code in it pasted from single.php and when I tried to change parts of it I noticed that nothing changes so for the sake of this question I deleted everything and still as if the Default template is selected.

Am I missing something here? How come the template name appears on the "Add Post" page but this template page does nothing? Not even I add a die(); at the top of the template page.

Comment: Try renaming your template to `single-gallery.php`

Answer (score 0):

is the page supposed to display single posts?... then according to the WordPress Codex Docs you will have to rename your file from

gallery-post.php **to** single-gallery.php

Now if it is just a **post-format** you will have to register it in your functions.php file and see if that works.

I hope it helps.